# Load SQL server backup file into DB2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, db2, database-backups

Is it possible to restore/import a SQL Server 2008 database backup file (`.bak`) into DB2 10.1?

Thanks

Comment: No you can't physically from SQL SERVER to DB2 without 3rd party tool

Comment: Are there any tools you would recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible; completely different format.

Restore to another SQL Server instance then migrate. IBM has resources for that. http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/migration/mtk/